# Is it possible to create a polymer-cased telescoped leadless ammunition (PCTLA) and would be cost effective to create them?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, weapons, military

I'm currently writing a military science fiction story, and I came across several different types of ammunition: leadless 'green' bullets, polymer-cased ammunition, and polymer-cased telescoped ammunition.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoped_ammunition

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer-cased_ammunition

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_bullet

Is it possible to create such a bullet and would it be to our advantage cost wise to create one?

If you want you may put in some problems with the creation of such a bullet.

Comment: Each of your links show examples of the described ammunition.  I conclude it is possible to create such a bullet.   Each link also has pros and cons.  I hate to make an answer made up of text pasted from links in the question.  Too easy!  How about you invent a bullet type not among those already existing and ask about that?

Comment: By advantage I mean cost effective.

Comment: Have you looked at the G11 which had telescopic caseless ammunition.

Comment: No I haven't.  I'll have to look at that.

Answer (score 4):

Polymer cased and telescoped ammunition was the basis of the [LSAT](https://www.popularmechanics.com/military/research/news/a27414/plastic-ammo-textron-cased-telescope/) program, which has evolved into the [Next Generation Squad Weapon](https://www.military.com/daily-news/2020/05/14/armys-next-generation-squad-weapon-big-hit-socom.html). The smaller size and weight of the polymer cased, telescoped rounds allows soldiers to either shed some weight while carrying the same amount of ammunition as today, or increase their load outs for the same amount of weight as they currently carry. So in terms of logistics, the polymer cased, telescoped ammunition is already a great plus.

[image]

*Sig Saur NGSW prototypes*

A little discussed secondaey avantage is the 6.8mm ammunition which is being considered for the NGSW also eliminates several weapons, another big logistical advantage. The "designated marksman" does not need a separate weapon and ammunition from the rest of the squad (perhaps simply substituting a different sight on the rifle), and having light machine guns and medium machine guns can be folded up into a single weapon. Carried by squad members and firing from a bipod, it makes an effective squad level weapon, while when mounted on a tripod, it serves as a medium machine gun (General Purpose Machine Gun for Commonwealth readers). This is much like how the MG-34/42 series of machine guns were used during WWII. Machine guns mounted on tripods have much greater range and accuracy, and can also be fired in an "indirect" mode to attack targets behind cover like low hills, once you understand the techniques.

[image]

*MG-42 on its tripod. Bipod mounted it can be used to engage to 2000m, on the tripod to 3500m, and 4,700m indirect*

So usng 6.8mm polymer cased telescoped ammunition provides each soldier the means to carry more ammunition, and eliminates the DM rifle and LMG from the Squad's table of equipment. The platoon only has one nature of small arms ammunition to deal with, and two types of small arms. The only ancilliary equipment needed is a DM sight, and a tripod for the platoon's support machine gun (ideally every gun is issued a tripod, but at the squad level, they will likely leave it with the qurtermaster unless digging into the defense).

As for the second part of the question, military ammunition has beem made using steel cores or penetrators since the 1990's with the adoption of the [SS 109 5.56mm](https://www.ar15.com/ammo/project/ammo_cross_sections/index.htm#SS109) round. The use of the steel penetrator, and the 1:8 rifling replacing the 1:12 rifling of earlier weapons allows infantry small arms to penetrate many types of body armour and protective equipment. Lead cores might have more sectional density, but the hard penetrator does not deform as much, providing the ability to penetrate body armour. While the SS 109 has the penetrator backed by a lead "pill", full steel cored AP ammunition exists, and other materials have been used in the past. Lead is favoured due to its density and low cost, which is important when you buy rounds by the millions.

[image]

*SS109 Ammunition from various nations*

Answer (score 3):

- Polymer-cased
  Maybe. One advantage of metallic cases is that they take thermal energy with them as they are ejected. It would take a good look at the tradeoffs involved. Shotguns have made the transition, after all.
- Telescoping
  Again maybe. The advantages of telescoping ammunition are in storage, which might apply to small arms as well as autocannon.
- Leadless
  Quite possibly, but not for the reason one might think. Sports shooters and hunters use leadless bullets (or lead-filled but carefully jacketed bullets) and less toxic [primers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primer_(firearms)) to preserve **their own health** as well as the environment, despite the higher pricetag.
  Military users might select leadless bullets because they find other materials superior for their needs. There were frenzied reports that Soviet 5.45mm bullets had an "air gap" to enhance tumbling. Other analysts said that it was not worth the effort to drive all the air *out* during manufacturing. Armor-piercing bullets might involve materials like steel and tungsten rather than lead.

Comment: Wow.  This is very interesting.

Comment: And depleted uranium is better than lead in some ways.  Or FTM gold & silver: the only drawback is cost :-)

Comment: @jamesqf Also serious health effects for depleted uranium, but no one worries until after the war. https://www.publichealth.va.gov/exposures/depleted_uranium/